# computing suprema and infima without proofs

Tags: real-analysis

i am trying to figure out how to compute suprema and infima without using proofs and i've gotten a bit confused.

i offer my answers to a and b because i see these as straightforward questions and i try to apply my reasoning from them to questions c and d. but i'm much less certain about my answers to c and d and i'd like to know where i'm going wrong.

a) {m / n: m, n $\in \mathbf N$ with m < n}

my answer is sup = $\frac{1}{2}$ and inf = 0. for the supremum, m and n are natural numbers and m < n, so these are the smallest values that both numbers can take at the same time. for the infimum, the smallest value m can take is 1 and the largest value n can take is $+\infty$, which produces zero.

b) {$(-1)^{m}$ / n: m, n $\in \mathbf N$}

for this one my answer is sup = 1 and inf = -1. very simple because the values in the set just alternate between -1 and 1.

c) {n / (3n + 1): n $\in \mathbf N$}

i am less sure that i am right here. for this one my answer is sup = $\frac{1}{3}$ and inf = $\frac{1}{4}$.

my reasoning for infimum is that when n takes its smallest value, this produces $\frac{1}{3 + 1} = \frac{1}{4}$. for the supremum, the largest value n can take is $+\infty$, so setting n equal to this gives $\frac{+\infty}{3 \cdot (+\infty) + 1} = \frac{1}{3}$.

d) {m / (m + n): m, n $\in \mathbf N$}

this is the question that confuses me most.

my answer for the supremum is sup = $\frac{1}{2}$ because this is what you get when you set m = n = 1.

my answer for the infimum is inf = $\frac{+\infty}{(+\infty) + (+\infty)} = \frac{1}{2}$ based on my reasoning from c.

am i correct here? if not, what should i be doing instead?

thanks in advance for any insights.

Answer (score 1):

For a), in your reasoning over the supremum is correct, but over what you are reasoning is incorrect, that is to say: yes, the smallest values $m$ and $n$ can take, respectively, are $1$ and $2$, but why should the smallest values that $m$ and $n$ can take should give you the supremum? Over $\mathbb{R}$, it is sometimes useful to "visualize" the set you are trying to obtain the supremum or infimum, and the set over you are picking $m$ and $n$, $\mathbb{N}$, is large: why limit yourself to small values of $m$ and $n$? Consider, for instance,$m=100$, $n=101$, they satisfy $m<n$, but their ratio is bigger than $1/2$. So, one can approach to $1$ by elements of the set in question, which are smaller than $1$. Can you find a reasoning on why they can't get bigger than 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a special attention to the definition of *infimum* and *supremum*. Following [***Mathematical Analysis by Rudin***](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Eagboola/teaching/2021/winter/122A/rudin.pdf) (Page 4, Definition 1.8) Supremum or the l.u.b (least upper bound) of an (nonempty) ordered set $A\subset X$, where $X$ is ordered and bounded above, is an element $\alpha\in X$ such that (i) $\alpha$ is an upper bound of $A$ and (ii) $\alpha$ is the smallest upper bound of $A$. The name *least upper bound* is given for this reason.

What do we mean by *upper bound of $A$*? It means for any $x\in A$ we have $x\le \alpha$ and the *least upper bound* means among all possible such upper bounds we choose the **least one**.

Example: Take $A=\{(-1)^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathbb{Z}$. It easy to see that for any $x\in A$ we have $-1\le x \le 1$, $-2\le x \le 2$, $-3\le x \le 3$ and so on. So the set of all upper bounds of $A$ is $U=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ similarly the set of all lower bounds of $A$ is $L=\{-1,-2,-3,\cdots\}$. Now what is the least element of $U$? Clearly $1$. Hence the $lub\ A=\sup A=1$.

In similar manner the *infimum* or the *glb* (greatest lower bound) of $A$ is the largest lower bound of $A$. What is the largest element in $L$ (in the above example)? Clearly $-1$. Which shows that $glb\ A=\inf A=-1$.

**Note:**  In some cases $\sup,\inf$ of a set can be $+\infty,-\infty$. These type of results are well known in Measure theory.

Now for your example (a) The supremum of the set $A=\{\frac{m}{n}:m,n\in\mathbb{N},m<n\}$ is $1$.

Proof: Clearly $1$ is an upper bound for $A$ as $m<n\implies \frac{m}{n}<1,\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}$. To show that $1$ is least we assume the contrary. Let $k<1$ be another upper bound of $A$. Then $\frac{m}{n}<k$ for all $m,n\in\mathbb N$. Choose $m=nk-1$ we see $n<\frac{1}{k}$. So choose $n=\lfloor\frac{1}{k}\rfloor+5$, where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function. Thus we have constructed a number $\displaystyle\frac{\lfloor \frac{1}{k}\rfloor+5}{k(\lfloor \frac{1}{k}\rfloor+5)-1}$ which is not less than $k$ and which belongs to $A$. This is a contradiction. Hence $1$ is the least upper bound of $A$.

For example $\frac{100}{101}=0.99...\not<\frac{1}{2}$, as you assumed.

(d) Recall that for any integer $n\in\mathbb N$ we must have $m<m+n$, hence $\frac{m}{m+n}<1$. In similar manner it can be shown that $\sup\{\frac{m}{m+n}:m,n\in\mathbb N\}=1$ (not $\frac{1}{2}$).

**Bonus qestion:** What is the supremum and infimum of *Null set*?